# Coverings of Heine-Borel.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Here is an extract  from [https://math.uc.edu/~halpern/calc.1/Ho/Heineborelthm.pdf](https://math.uc.edu/%7Ehalpern/calc.1/Ho/Heineborelthm.pdf)

Some words and sentences were cut and modified to avoid wordiness

> **Theorem:** Let $\mathcal F$ be a family of open intervals (set) that covers the closed interval $[a.b]$. Then $F$ has a finite subcover.
>
> *Proof*. Let $B = \{x : a\leq x \leq b, \text{and} \; [a,x] \; \text{has a finite subcover} \}$. Then $B$ is nonempty since it contains $a$ and has an upper bound $b$, so the set $B$ has a least upper bound $x_0$. First we see that $x_0$ is in $B$. If not, then let $(c,d)$ be the open interval (set) in $\mathcal F$ that contains $x_0$, then there has to be some element $x \in B$ in the open set $(c,x_0)$. Since $x \in B$, we have $F_1,\dots, F_n$ in $\mathcal F$ that covers $[a,x]$. Now the intervals $F_1, \dots, F_n$, $(c,d)$ in $\mathcal F$ cover $[a,x_0]$. So $x_0 \in B$. Second we show $x_0 = b$. Suppose $x_0 < b$, then $[a,x_0]$ the finite family $F_1, \dots, F_n, (c,d) = F_{n+1}$ in $\mathcal F$ would cover $[a,d]$ and $x_0$ would not be an upper bound of $B$. So we have found finitely many intervals (sets) that cover $[a,b]$

For the proof of the Hein-Borel Theorem, how does $F_{n+1}$ cover $[a,d]$? The open set $(c,d)$ doesn't touch $d$ and I think we are to assume $d < b$. In fact the other cover, $F_1, \dots, F_n$ doesn't touch anywhere near $d$ either.

**EDIT**

I also have a counterexample to the proof

[image]

I have three open sets: blue, red, and purple. Blue set only covers up until $x$, purple set
covers a small portion around $x_0$, leaving a gap in between blue and purple. The red set is what covers the rest of the interval.

**Remark** I looked at Spivak's Manifold book and I have noticed he uses the words "interval" and $U$ (open set) separately. Is there a reason for this?

> [image]

**EDIT#2** okay I figured out the yellow text. Basically he is saying the values less than $\alpha$ (he calls them "$x$") must live in $A$. If I am wrong, correct me. Also, why exactly is my picture wrong then?

Comment: [As I've reminded you before](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360046/compactness-closed-and-bounded-heine-borel#comment773628_360046): to avoid future link rot, please copy down as much of the relevant information as possible into your question. At minimum, take a screenshot and include it as an image in your question.

Comment: I didn't think the link would be broken since it came from a university source.

Comment: (And still, copy-typing the text would be preferred)

Comment: One moment please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what was wrong with my initial problem. I kept thinking that a particular open set gave rise to a contradiction. But the whole proof hinges on the fact that it is saying there is *some* interval that does this job.

Sure you can find one that doesn't work, but it's saying that even if one interval works, then it's all good.

In my picture $x$ still lives in the red interval, making it a member of $A$.

Answer (score 2):

The text should  better read "... if $(c,d)$ is **an** open interval in $\mathcal F$ that contains $x_0$ ..." in the first part. Also, you are right: we (immediately) only get that $ F_{n+1}$ covers $[a,d)$, but that still shows that $x_0$ is not an upper boud for $B$, as witnessed by any element of the non-empty  set $(x_0,b]\cap [a,d)$, for example by $x_1=\min\{\frac{x_0+d}2,b\}$.

Also note that we cannot a priori assume $d\le b$ as the covering property of $\mathcal F$ allows it to actually cover *more* than just $[a,b]$ (and that is necesarily the case).

Comment: Sorry, isn't $(x_0, b] \cap [a, d) = (x_0, d)$?

Comment: Do you mind reading my edit? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As worded and stated, the proof is indeed incorrect, since the cover given by $F_1, \dots, F_n, (c, d) = F_{n+1}$ covers only the interval $[a, d)$.  It is possible that $d > b$, for example, the collection $\{ (-2, \frac{3}{4}), (\frac{1}{2}, 2) \}$ is an open cover of the interval $[0, 1]$.  If $d>b$ we're done, since we already have a finite subcover of $[a, b]$ and can disregard the details regarding upper bounds of $B$ and so forth.  However, since you can't assume $d>b$, take for the sake of argument that $d \le b$.  Then $d \in [a, b]$ (since $(c, d)$ contains an element, namely $x_0$, of $[a, b]$), so there is some element of $\mathcal{F}$, call it $F_{n+2}$ such that $d \in F_{n+2}$.  Then $F_1, F_2, \dots , F_{n+2}$ forms an open cover of $[a, d]$, so that $d \in B$ contradicting that $x_0$ is an upper bound of $B$.  This completes and corrects the proof from the UC link.

Regarding the remark about Spivak's use of "interval" and "open set", recall that $[a, b], [a, b), (a, b], (a, b)$ are all considered intervals in the real line by a lot of authors (for example Rudin, Ross, Stein, Stewart), and I believe Spivak does as well, but only $(a, b)$ is open in the usual sense here.  He's saying that all points in some interval $(c, \alpha]$ lie in this set $A$.  I think this is what you were saying in edit #2 as well.

Finally, regarding your picture, my understanding is that you're arguing the gap between the blue set and the purple set means our finite collection omits some points in $[a, b]$ and cannot be an open cover, where the blue set is $\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^n F_k$.  However, your picture has $x$ outside the interval $(c, d)$, which contradicts the very definition of $x$ in the proof, so that the picture is not a counterexample of the proof.

Comment: This is from your excerpt from the UC link.  "First we see that x0 is in B. If not, then let (c,d) be the open interval (set) in  that contains x0, then there has to be some element x∈B in the open set (c,x0)."  This clearly defines where $x$ is, contradicting your picture.

Comment: The $\alpha$ in Spivak's proof is the $x_0$ in the UC proof.  The fact that $\alpha$ is the least upper bound implies that $x \in B$, so that there is a finite covering $F_1, \dots, F_n$ of $[a, x]$.  The location of $x$, so long as we maintain $x < \alpha$, is independent of the fact that $\alpha$ is a least upper bound.

Comment: $\alpha$ being the least upper bound of $B$ means that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is some $x \in B$ such that $|s-\alpha|<\epsilon$.  Since $(c, d)$ is an open interval containing $x_0 = \alpha$, we can pick some $\epsilon > 0$ such that $(\alpha - \epsilon, \alpha+\epsilon) \subset (c, d)$ (this is the definition of openness).  Using both of these we can pick and $x \in B$ such that $x \in (c, d)$ as well.

Comment: OK, the first thing to keep clear is that $B$ is not a set of finite subcovers, but rather the set of all points $x$ in $[a, b]$ such that $[a, x]$ has a finite subcover.  So now you're asking why $(c, d)$ overlaps with the finite subcover of $[a, x]$ for some $x \in B$.  The logic is exactly the same logic used in my last comment, word for word.  (By the way, in the first line of my last comment I meant $|x-\alpha| < \epsilon$, not $|s-\alpha|$.)

Comment: Look back at the definition of $B$. $B$ is the set of all such $x$.  That's how you read set builder notation.  However, if Spivak defined $A$ differently than the UC link defined $B$, I wouldn't know, because you don't have the definition of $A$ posted in your original question.

Comment: No it is the same definition; basically because $(c,d)$ or rather $U$ (in Spivak) is an open cover that makes $(c, x)$ living in $B$ or $A$ if we are referring to Spivak's proof. So my picture can never happen?

Comment: Correct, under the definitions of Spivak's proof your picture can never happen.  Are you beginning to understand the proof or are you still having troubles?

Comment: If I replace $U$ with $(c,d)$, then "some interval" (Spivak) is also $(c,d)$, but *left* of this interval is $(c,\alpha)$

Comment: Yes, but the case with $x \in (\alpha, d)$ is trivial, since then $[a, \alpha]\subset[a, x]$, which has a finite subcover already.

Comment: *However, your picture has $x$ outside the interval*. I want to make one remark. I think I was saying that if $x \in (c,d)$ (or $U$), then it doesn't necessary have to be in $A$ or in $[a,x]$